# Death becomes her?? But in real life

Tags: noah, ark-of-noah, seth

I’m doing some research if you could help. Question 1 How Is living a long life (900+ years) like some of Seth’s descendants not a direct sign of divinity. I’m not super religious but the grouping I’ve been working with lately helped me come to this understanding “things that shouldn’t have happened aren’t deeply explained and aren’t harmful/negative I tend to take as a sign or divinity.” Just bc there’s already so much unknown when it comes to religion an unnatural GOOD thing I just take as  divinity amongst earth. That leads me to my next question multiple descendants of Seth lived to be 900+ That’s a direct sign of divinity (to me and my grouping) so if anyone has any insight any scripture you could point me too of what lifestyle these people (descendants of Seth ppl who have lived 900+) Kept any scripture where their character is mentioned that allotted them SUCH a long life. & ultimately what could’ve happened to tarnish that family to the point Noah was the only pure blood and no one lives to be 900 anymore. I’m very open minded opinions welcomed this is less about religion as a whole more about living to be 900 how that was possible and could be possible again The Bible is interpreted a lot of ways so any feedback is welcomed

Also I did see something about the calendar being different and some don’t believe they were actually that old.. saying it’s an exaggeration in writing

Comment: related cross post: https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/74390/18064

Comment: Welcome to Christianity.SE! and thank you for your contribution. When you get a chance, please take the [tour] to understand how the site works and [how it is different than others](https://christianity.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1809/50259). I would also recommend reading the [Help Center](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/help)'s sections on asking and answering questions.

Comment: The Title question is incomprehensible, and the Body itself doesn't contain any actual question. Please rewrite this more simply, asking a single specific question. See the [Tour](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/tour) page for this site.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple; it has nothing to do with divinity, even less to do with lifestyle, and everything to do with genetics.

We know from modern genetics that inbreeding tends to result in... problems.

We know from Scripture that the human population was at one point reduced to eight individuals. In fact, you (almost) answered your own question: "Noah was the only pure blood". This isn't strictly true; all eight people on the ark were "pure blood"... but *their* descendants weren't, and Scripture records life expectancy taking a nosedive in the next generations before stabilizing again at about what it is today.

Obviously, we don't know exactly what genes were lost or altered, but by far the most reasonable explanation is that the genetic bottleneck caused by the Flood resulted in *some* manner of genetic degradation, which in turn lead to the much shorter life expectancy we have today. This is also consistent with the effect taking several generations to be fully realized.